# String literal in resource path

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm writing a WebApi OData service (using `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` v6 package) for an ERP system and I'm running into a bit of issues.
The system has multiple modules (Sales, Purchase, Management...) and I'm trying to reflect this in my service.

For example, I have an entity "SalesOrders" and an entity "PurchaseOrders". These are different from each other, and I would like to expose these via different OData routes.

For SalesOrders, I'd like my route to be `~/odata/Sales/Orders` while PurchaseOrders should be under `~/odata/Purchase/Orders`.

Unfortunately I've been unable to get this to work, because OData keeps telling me that "Sales" and "Purchase" are not valid OData path segments (which is correct, as these are not my entity): `Resource not found for segment 'Sales'`

I could use different models, linked to different routes (using a workaround for a ModelBoundODataRoute found [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/220)), but then I won't have a unified `$metadata` document. I could probably get away with writing a custom ControllerSelector (possibly a NamespaceAwareControllerSelector, or maybe using some kind of marker attributes), but that's a whole different can of worms I'd rather avoid if possible. Last resort would be to just not try to divide this up and use entities called PurchaseOrder, SalesOrder and so on.

```
    WebApiConfig.Register:
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //OData routes
        var salesModel = ModelBuilder.GetSalesModel(); // this just builds an edm model with the required entities
        config.MapModelBoundODataServiceRoute(routeName: "salesRoute", routePrefix: "odata/Sales", configureAction: action =>
        {
            action.AddDefaultODataServices()
            .AddService<IEdmModel>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => salesModel)
            .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
            {
                return ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()
                .Concat(new[] { new ModelBoundODataAttributeRoutingConvention(salesModel, "salesRoute", config) });
            })
        });

        var purchaseModel = ModelBuilder.GetPurchaseModel();
        config.MapModelBoundODataServiceRoute(routeName: "purchaseRoute", routePrefix: "odata/Purchase", configureAction: action =>
        {
            action.AddDefaultODataServices()
            .AddService<IEdmModel>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => purchaseModel)
            .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
            {
                return ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()
                .Concat(new[] { new ModelBoundODataAttributeRoutingConvention(purchaseModel, "purchaseRoute", config) });
            })
        });
    }
```

Is there any way to add a string literal (not mapping to a resource) to the OData route prefix, while preserving a single unified $metadata document?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option may be to use Containment to do this

This would involve having a singleton named `Sales` with a contained navigation property called `Orders` and a singleton named `Purchase` with a contained navigation property named `Orders`. This does raise the interesting question of what should be returned when you ask for the singleton `Sales` using the URL `~/odata/Sales` but it would give you the URLs that you are looking for. For more details, see the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-containment-in-web-api-22

Comment: That seems very... hacky. Although it would probably work. I'd probably have to revisit my controllers and add ODataRoutePrefix'es to every one of them. And I'm not sure how my Swagger integration will work with it, but definitely something to try.